# How to Switching between launchers of Android Programatically

Tags: java, android, android-launcher

I have two launcher, Android Launcher and my custom launcher. My custom launcher is the default launcher.when the android device bots up, it launches my application. What i want to do is that, when user press some buttom in the my launcher, I want to launch the android launcher(comes with android) without asking the user to select the launcher. I want to do it just like launching any other application.

Is this possible with android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible unless the device is rooted, before android 2.2 there was a method through which you could do it, but it is no longer available.

But if the device is rooted or your app is a "system" app (is in /system/apps folder), then you can just disable other Launcher applications when your app starts and re-enable them when your app exits, this way your launcher becomes the only launcher in the system, hence it will be implicitly treated as the default launcher (but you need to handle "back" button in your Launcher activity, home button will work fine)

Comment: If my app is a system app, then how can I launch the android's default launcher as an application

Answer (score 0):

You can try that

```
Intent intent=null;
final PackageManager packageManager=getPackageManager();
for(final ResolveInfo resolveInfo:packageManager.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME), PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY))
{ 
    if(!getPackageName().equals(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName))  
        //if this activity is not in our activity (in other words, it's another default home screen)
    { 
        intent=packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        break; 
    } 
} 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank u for the quick replay.  I just tried that, but I am getting the bellow error.

Comment: Process: me.xxxxx.xxxxx.homescreen, PID: 2474
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData()' on a null object reference
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1494)

Comment: try again please, I have updated my answer. I have tested the code that i posted and it worked

Comment: please find the code and error https://gist.github.com/anonymous/258549feb2a1f3eb5574

Comment: as I can see from the error it didn't find any other application as launcher. The intent was null and then crashes

Comment: I am running this on android tv emulator. Before running the application I made sure that there is com.google.android.leenbacklauncher then why is it not able to start that launcher??